# diy tornado on openshift socket error

Tags: python, sockets, tornado, openshift

I try to deploy a tornado by myself on openshift diy cartridges but meet some problem.

I have installed python 2.7.6 and tornado 3.2, and tried to run the tornado hello world demo on it. But it always went error. In addition, I have executed the chmod 777 instruction for $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy.

Here followings are what I did and the error logs. How can I solve this problem and start my application?

#### 1.pre-install:

1. python 2.7.6 in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
2. tornado 3.2 via pip

#### 2.tornado code

This file named start.py is the only file in $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

#### 3.action_hooks files:

start:

`nohup $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/bin/python $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/start.py > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/tornado_server.log 2>&1 &`

stop:

```
source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

if [ -z "$(ps -ef | grep start.py | grep -v grep)" ]
then
    client_result "Application is already stopped"
else
    kill `ps -ef | grep start.py | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'` 
    > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

#### 4.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../app-root/runtime/repo//diy/start.py",
line 13, in <module>
    application.listen(8080)
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py",
line 1559, in listen
    server.listen(port, address)
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py",
line 117, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py",
line 104, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work because you have to bind to $OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP and $OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT. Instead of `application.listen(8080)` use following code

```
ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP']
port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT'])
application.listen(port , ip)
```

Also, I have written a blog that could help you https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-25-tornado-combining-tornado-mongodb-and-angularjs-to-build-an-app

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use DIY cartridge to deploy Tornado on Openshift.

check this repo for example: https://github.com/avinassh/openshift-tornado-starter